# How to make sure a resource is destroyed before the resources in some module in terraform?

Tags: terraform

I have a module that sets up default access to a key vault. Then I have a resource that sets up a secret in the key vault:

```
module "default_kv_access" {
  source = "../default_kv_access"
  key_vault = azurerm_key_vault.kv
}
...
resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "secrets" {
  for_each = local.secrets

  name         = each.key
  value        = each.value
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.kv.id
}
```

When destroyed, terraform first destroys the module and then attempts to destroy the secrets (wasteful, because the key vault would be destroyed anyway, but given).

Anyway, by destroying the module first, terraform removes all the access policies and so when it comes to destroying the `azurerm_key_vault_secret` resource - it fails, because the service principal running the code does not have the necessary access to the secrets.

What I need is tell terraform that `azurerm_key_vault_secret` depends on the `default_kv_access` module.

So, the question is how can I do it, given that I cannot just mention the module in the `depends_on` statement.

**EDIT 1**

The module code is:

```
variable "key_vault" {}

locals {
  ctx = jsondecode(file("${path.root}/../${basename(abspath(path.root)) == "product" ? "" : "../"}metadata.g.json"))

  # Will have to be replaced when the hosting is ready
  hosting_ad_group_name = "AdminRole-Product-DFDevelopmentOps"
}

data "azurerm_client_config" "client" {}

data "azuread_service_principal" "hosting_sp" {
  display_name = local.ctx.HostingAppName
}

data "azuread_group" "hosting_ad_group" {
  name = local.hosting_ad_group_name
}

locals {
  allow_kv_access_to = {
    client = {
      object_id          = data.azurerm_client_config.client.object_id
      secret_permissions = ["get", "set", "list", "delete", "recover", "backup", "restore"]
    }
    hosting_sp = {
      object_id          = data.azuread_service_principal.hosting_sp.object_id
      secret_permissions = ["get", "set", "list", "delete", "recover", "backup", "restore"]
    }
    hosting_ad_group = {
      object_id          = data.azuread_group.hosting_ad_group.id
      secret_permissions = ["get", "list"]
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "default" {
  for_each = local.allow_kv_access_to

  key_vault_id = var.key_vault.id
  tenant_id    = var.key_vault.tenant_id
  object_id    = each.value.object_id

  secret_permissions = each.value.secret_permissions
}
```

Comment: Can you share the module source as well please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way I've seen this done (`depends_on` with a module) is to reference a property of the module in a `locals` property, then `depends_on` that local reference in your resource. I have this working in a few of my own configurations and I get the desired outcome, the resource is not destroyed or created before the module.

Example:

```
module "default_kv_access" {
  source = "../default_kv_access"
  key_vault = azurerm_key_vault.kv
}

locals {
  module_depends_on = module.default_kv_access.name
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "secrets" {
  depends_on = [local.module_depends_on]
  for_each = local.secrets

  name         = each.key
  value        = each.value
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.kv.id
}
```

Comment: Interesting. I need to test it.

Comment: I actually use a similar approach, but I reference the module output in the tags. I did not know `depends_on` can reference local variables.